# What do you call a corridor inside a barn?

Tags: word-request

[image: 1]

I feel like this could have a particular name, but I would just call it lane or corridor, I am not sure if there's a better word for it though.

Comment: I would call it the **central aisle** or **the row between the stalls** (though that second one might be ambiguous, as it could refer to an aisle perpendicular to the main aisle). If there is a specific term for it, I am not aware of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the word you are seeking is a ***"drive"***

> I fix really old barns for a living and they actually were pretty utilitarian and practical when they were built. Everything was designed on a gravity system and ***the main drives*** had floor planks used for threshing grain. This was obviously before the advent of petroleum powered threshers but as usual just look into the past a little bit and its all there. Most of the information on this site has already been talked about 100 plus years ago.

Dictionary definition is: ***A drive is a wide piece of hard ground*** although it tends, nowadays, to be predominantly related to a type of roadway linking a house.